# Trim a string before and after certain characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, trim

I've got a really nasty string that looks like this (not actal rendered HTML, but a **string**):

```
<div class='isc-content-block' data-contentmanagerid='60dd19b0-e3ba-4629-935c-a2dd00e052b8' data-contentmanagername='Product: B456009805'>456009806</div>
```

I need to get the value, the number showing up as "456009806".
What would be the best way to trim this string to remove the tags so all that is left is the number inside?

Comment: The best way to parse html is to use `HtmlAgilityPack`. Then it's simple: `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='isc-content-block']").InnerText;`

Comment: Agreed. HtmlAgilityPack is the best for parsing HTML tags!

Comment: If it's always gonna look that way, then just remove everything between < and > and you end up with the number. You can do it with a Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No third party dependency with this solution. If you know the HTML format each time and it's not for a very complicated procedure, then use a simple Regex and adjust accordingly.

Simple solution:

```
var result = Regex.Match("<div class='isc-content-block' data-contentmanagerid='60dd19b0-e3ba-4629-935c-a2dd00e052b8' data-contentmanagername='Product: B456009805'>456009806</div>", ">(.*)</.*>");

result.Groups[1].Value
```

Will give you:

```
456009806
```

UPDATE:

Also, running some performance tests with Substring, standard Regex and Compiled regex is pretty amazing. Tried my best to get  accurate results with the jitter warmup code and using ticks from `StopWatch`.

[Gist for Linqpad](https://gist.github.com/pjmagee/a69d60ae2c3c847ed572)

Here is a picture of the results:

[image: Results from Linqpad with /o+ compiler flag enabled]

Comment: +1 for this. Some people are quick to dismiss regex as a sledgehammer being used for brain surgery, but sometimes it's the right tool for the job!

Comment: @Equalsk and with compiled regex, what more could you want? :D

Answer (score 1):

RegEx it, or if you are in a hurry:

```
// Assuming s is your string
string result = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(">") + 1).Replace("</div>", string.Empty);
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = @"<div class='isc-content-block' data-contentmanagerid='60dd19b0-e3ba-4629-935c-a2dd00e052b8' data-contentmanagername='Product: B456009805'>456009806</div>";

Regex regex = new Regex("<.*?>");
var justnumstr = regex.Replace(str, string.Empty);
```

This will result in `justnumstr`containing a string of `456009806`